# SQL query with multiple SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table to present in my app, and what i want is to present table, in which one row have values that calculated by following:

```
SELECT SUM (val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov 
  WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = ? AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = ?
```

For first row i want to present 4 values, each one will look like that:

```
SELECT SUM (val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov 
  WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = (1,2,3,4) AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1
```

Where (1,2,3,4) are 4 different SELECT statements with (1,2,3,4) values correspondingly. In next row i will change `rov.orbiting_group_indice_id` = 2 and want to use same `rov.orbiting_group_type_id` values (1,2,3,4).

Im new at SQL and i want to ask, how to present table with that valeus? 
So it should be something like column1-value, column2-value, column3-value, column4-value.

Thanks!

Updated: I want something like following:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT
        SUM(val)
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals rov
    WHERE
        rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
    AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1) as colOne,
(SELECT
        SUM(val)
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals rov
    WHERE
        rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
    AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 2) as colTwo,
(SELECT
        SUM(val)
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals rov
    WHERE
        rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
    AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 3) as colThree,
(SELECT
        SUM(val)
    FROM
        report_orbiting_vals rov
    WHERE
        rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
    AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 4) as colFourth
```

Unfortunately, above code not work, it produce an error, but i hope you understand what i want for now.

Updated (2):

I tried 2 solutions provided below, first one:

```
SELECT
(SELECT
 SUM(val)
 FROM
 report_orbitings rov
 WHERE
 rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
 AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1) as colOne,
(SELECT
 SUM(val)
 FROM
 report_orbitings rov
 WHERE
 rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
 AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 2) as colTwo,
(SELECT
 SUM(val)
 FROM
 report_orbitings rov
 WHERE
 rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
 AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 3) as colThree,
(SELECT
 SUM(val)
 FROM
 report_orbitings rov
 WHERE
 rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1
 AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 4) as colFourth
FROM report_orbitings rv
```

Output:

[image]

While second:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type1_sum,
SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 2 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type2_sum,
SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 3 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type3_sum,
SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type4_sum
FROM report_orbitings rov
WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id in (1,2,3,4)
AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1
```

Output:

[image]

To be clear i want to admit, that my data base don't have data yet, just structure. Still, i suppose second code work while first does not, because it output [Null] instead of nothing. Why is there difference in those 2 examples? It should produce identical output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I followed, either you want the total sum of them, then you need to use `IN()` :

```
SELECT SUM (val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id in (1,2,3,4) 
  AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1
```

Or you want the sum of each one in a different column :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 1 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type1_sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 2 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type2_sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 3 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type3_sum,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 4 THEN val ELSE 0 END) as type4_sum
FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id in (1,2,3,4) 
  AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1
```

Comment: thank you, i many not make myself clear, i want to each select from your question will be  SELECT SUM (val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id =  AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1, next one SELECT SUM (val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = 2 AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1, next one 3, last 4.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban That's what my query does, it will return the result in each column .

Comment: thank you, but could you explain meaning of WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id in (1,2,3,4)? Isnt it neccesarry when we explicity set those values in queries?

Comment: That's just for performance , you can remove that part. I used it to tell the optimizer to scan only `id 1,2,3,4` . @EvgeniyKleban

Comment: would you be so kind to look at my updated answer and tell me, why your answer is work in compare to other one? Or maybe both works?

Comment: They will output the exact same thing, (If you add a filter to @i486 solution) , nothing is basically the same as null. These two queries has the same functionality ,  but my does it will 1 select from the table as opposed to 5 .

Comment: thank you, i understand, i was afraid there is an error in one of the snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
   WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = rv.orbiting_group_type_id
   AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 1) as colOne,
  (SELECT SUM(val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
   WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = rv.orbiting_group_type_id
   AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 2) as colTwo,
  (SELECT SUM(val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
   WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = rv.orbiting_group_type_id
   AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 3) as colThree,
  (SELECT SUM(val) FROM report_orbiting_vals rov
   WHERE rov.orbiting_group_type_id = rv.orbiting_group_type_id
  AND rov.orbiting_group_indice_id = 4) as colFourth,
  rv.orbiting_group_type_id
FROM report_orbiting_vals rv
```

Comment: thank you, your asnwer is correct, but could you please explain why my updated code not working? I guess it is identical to your solution

Comment: See the last row in my query - your updated code does not have second `FROM report_orbiting_vals`.

Comment: Wow that's 4 unnecessary selects!

Comment: @sagi We don't know the DB structure - I hope `SUM(val)` will include more than 1 row.